# The constructor is undefined?

Tags: java, constructor

Can someone please help me with this error. I am trying to learn java on my own and not sure what is causing the error?

```
/*
 * Without changing the Point class, add any arguments to the constructor
 * below so that the error goes away.
 */

public Point p04Constructor() {
    return new Point(); 
}
```

Here is the Point class:

```
public class Point {

private int _x;
private int _y;

public Point(int x, int y) {
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
}

public void move(int dx, int dy) {
    _x = _x + dx;
    _y = _y + dy;
}

public void flip() {
    _x = _y;
    _y = _x;
}

public void setY(int _y) {
    _y = 2;
}

public int getY() {
    return _y;
}

public String toString() {
    return "(" + _x + "," + _y + ")";
}
```

}

Please let me know what you think. I already tried doing what was suggested in the comments and continue to get errors.

Comment: Can you show us your point class ?

Comment: The error says "The constructor Point() is undefined"

Comment: ... look at the comment.. kind of looks like an assignment so you probably need to add something to the `Point()` to make the error go away..

Comment: e.g. `new Point(0, 4);`

Comment: So I should add something inside the parentheses? I will go try that

Comment: there's no default constructor in Point. You can have use the constructor that takes arguments.

Comment: ... and we can't tell what those arguments should be for sure, without seeing the `Point `class. maraca's suggestion sounds likely though.

Comment: everything I try, I keep getting errors ughhhh. I will keep trying tho

Comment: @TheCookieMonster programming shouldn't be a guessing game, you should be able to figure it out by looking at the constructor(s) of your `Point` class instead of just randomly trying values.

Comment: you Point constructor expects x and y. Point(int x, int y)

Answer (score 1):

To add to Austin's answer...

There are a couple of other issues as well...

The setY(int y) method will always set the _y value to 2 instead of the method parameter y.

The flip method won't work as you're expecting.  Once _x is set to _y, then _y will just be set to _x, which was just set to _y.

There is no getX() method.

Comment: Yea my job is to fix those errors

Answer (score 0):

As others in the comment have said, you need to pass the correct parameters for the constructor. So something like this should compile.

```
 public Point p04Constructor() {
    return new Point(0, 0); 
 }
```

You need to add 2 `int` parameters since the `Point` class you gave us only has one constructor, and it requires 2 `int` variables to be passed to it.

```
public Point(int x, int y) {
```

Comment: You are the best. Thank you :)

Comment: Austin, I see you've edited the post above. However it still could use some editing. Clearly there is code left outisde of the code blocks, and the error is excluded but listed in the comments. I don't see how you decided whatever you did was sufficient enough to finish your edit. I'm not saying that you didn't improve the question's formatting, I'm just curious as to why you stopped where you did.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt I'm not really sure what else you want in my answer to be honest. The OP was asking specifically about the undefined constructor error, so I showed him how to fix it and how the constructor works...

Comment: I wasn't talking about your answer. I was talking about how you edited the question.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt O, well in that case I just removed the Eclipse tag as that wasn't relevant to the question. I didn't edit the body of the post.